# Laravel iOS APN push 403 expired provider token

Tags: php, laravel, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently using laravel 7 and laravel-notification-channels/apn for iOS push notification. I also have a worker that handles sending notifications.

When I send a push notification to iOS it works fine initially but eventually, I got a 403 provider token expired. I can restart the worker to get the notification working again but how can I refresh a token without restarting a server? I have a production on Heroku and I don't think that would work in practice.

Thanks!

Comment: The solution will be to refresh the token inside of the queued job, I imagine. If you don't want to refresh it every time the job processes, you could cache the value for a specified period of time and refresh it when the cache expires.

Comment: How do you trace where was the token was created? I'm testing by injecting my own instance of pushok/client and token create from a singleton of a manager class I create so I can create a cron job to refresh it.